# Android Studio HAXM Not installed

Tags: android, emulation, haxm

HAXM is not getting installed after installing also.

In my BIOS, I have enabled VT-X this is also not working any suggestions or help would be helpful.

I'm using Lenovo ThinkPad x220(intel(R) CORE TM i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50 GHz).

Comment: i m using windows 7 os

Answer (score 0):

HAXM and Hyper-V can't work at the same time. Try unchecking **Hyper-V** and **Windows Hypervisor Platform** under *Search bar -> Turn Windows Features on or off*. Also, try installing HAXM from their repository https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.6.5 instead of going through Android Studio. That worked for me.

[Windows Features Hyper-V unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJXRA.png)